# Im trying to add a div for just one category

Tags: categories

So as the title says im trying to add a div class to the thumbnails from a single category.
Im trying to use this code:

```
 if (in_category( 'Expired' )) : ?><div class="expire">
```

This is the single post code im trying to add it to:

```
 <?php
        if(has_post_thumbnail())  {
            the_post_thumbnail(
                array($theme->get_option('featured_image_width_single'), $theme->get_option('featured_image_height_single')),
                array("class" => $theme->get_option('featured_image_position_single') . " featured_image")
            );
        }
    ?>
```

And this is the div class ive created in the stylesheet:

```
.expire {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
background:url(images/sample-expired.png) no-repeat ;
width: 100px;
height:60px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
border-radius: 10px;
left: 2px;
}
```

Any ideas where in the code I should paste this? or any help as to getting this implemented? Thanks heaps

Comment: What is the final HTML supposed to look like? Do you want to add the class to the image tag?

Comment: Im just wanting a banner image overlayed on the thumbnail for the category "expired", ive been trying for weeks to acheive it, usually with trial and error i can move around the code and get things implemented, but this has me stumped.

Comment: This is the page if it helps anyone
          http://www.ez007.net/FreeSamplesAustraliaByMailOnly/expired/grab-1-of-780-elseve-sos-hair-total-repair-toluna/

Answer (score 0):

To wrap the thumbnail wit  I would do something like this:

First. Create the expire class string

```
$expire_class = in_category('expired') ? 'expire' : '';
```

Then, wrap your post thumbnail code with this:

```
<div class='<?php echo $expire_class; ?>' > 
[put your thumbnail code here]
</div>
```

So, it looks like this:

```
<?php
$expire_class = in_category('expired') ? 'expire' : '';
if(has_post_thumbnail())  {
        ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class='<?php echo $expire_class; ?>' > <?php the_post_thumbnail(
            array($theme->get_option('featured_image_width'), $theme->get_option('featured_image_height')),
            array("class" => $theme->get_option('featured_image_position') . " featured_image")
        ); ?></div></a><?php  
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, where do i put the expire class string exactly?

Comment: Just above `if(has_post_thumbnail())`

Comment: how does this look? it seems to have made no change?

Comment: ugh i cant work out how to format the comment as code, usually pressing control K works but not in comments for some reason... sorry im being a pain in the ass lol

Comment: It seems that you've mixed PHP and HTML code. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: thanks for all your help, still no change to the thumbnail though. Im not smart enough to work out why sadly. But again thanks for your time mate

Comment: Ive just realised i was editing the post.php file, when i should have been editing the post-single.php

The code differs slightly but using your method the whole page ceases to display?